# Ext.grid.Panel not loading data from Ext.data.Store

Tags: ajax, extjs4.1

I am trying to populate an ExtJS grid Panel from a Store using the following code :

app.js

```
Ext.define('UC', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['PMNumber']
});

var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeID :'s',
    model: 'UC',
    proxy: {
        type:'ajax',
        url:'data.php',
        reader: {
            type : 'json',      
            root: "myInventory",
            fields: [
                {name: 'PMNumber', type: 'int', mapping: 'PMNumber'},
            ]
        }
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() 
{
    ds.load();
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Attendanace',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('s'),
        columns: [
            { int: 'PMNumber',  dataIndex: 'PMNumber' }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: document.getElementById('aa')
    });
});
```

data.php is returning Following data in JSON format when called separately

```
{"myInventory":[{"PMNumber":"2003010001"},{"PMNumber":"2003010002"}]}
```

Anybody where am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: In the code you provided there was `({` after `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',`; was that a typo? Anyhow, I've edited your code. I'm not sure why you provide fields to your proxy. It should map properly to your model. Can you try removing the `fields` config and tell us what happens?

Comment: removed the config, still the same :(

Comment: I'd progress by checking if the store load properly by providing a success handler for load, and console.log the store there to see if the records were loaded properly.

Comment: solved it by changing   store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('s'), to   store: ds